# ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from partially initialized module 'telegram'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm getting this error whenever I use the command *pip install telegram-bot* in cmd:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>pip install telegram-bot
Collecting telegram-bot
Using cached telegram-bot-0.1.tar.gz (51 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\miclo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j1l7uwqx\\telegram-bot_a7d2b1d51c264e718c85210726554603\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\miclo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j1l7uwqx\\telegram-bot_a7d2b1d51c264e718c85210726554603\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-4qf8pb7l'
         cwd: C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j1l7uwqx\telegram-bot_a7d2b1d51c264e718c85210726554603\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j1l7uwqx\telegram-bot_a7d2b1d51c264e718c85210726554603\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        import telegram
      File "C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j1l7uwqx\telegram-bot_a7d2b1d51c264e718c85210726554603\telegram\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from telegram import Bot, ChatActions
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from partially initialized module 'telegram' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j1l7uwqx\telegram-bot_a7d2b1d51c264e718c85210726554603\telegram\__init__.py)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have installed the latest version of Python and upgraded pip, but nothing changed. I use *Pycharm* as IDE. When I try to install this module from Pycharm, I get the same error:

```
Collecting telegram-bot
  Using cached telegram-bot-0.1.tar.gz (51 kB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated and has no effect anymore. pip 21.1 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Development\telegram\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\miclo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-60osryel\\telegram-bot_02585524af70443f98a2a69b3da7ae38\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\miclo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-60osryel\\telegram-bot_02585524af70443f98a2a69b3da7ae38\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-0ihid_ld'
         cwd: C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60osryel\telegram-bot_02585524af70443f98a2a69b3da7ae38\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60osryel\telegram-bot_02585524af70443f98a2a69b3da7ae38\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        import telegram
      File "C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60osryel\telegram-bot_02585524af70443f98a2a69b3da7ae38\telegram\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from telegram import Bot, ChatActions
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from partially initialized module 'telegram' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\miclo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-60osryel\telegram-bot_02585524af70443f98a2a69b3da7ae38\telegram\__init__.py)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm trying to build a telegram bot and host it with Heroku. When typing *heroku logs -t* in cmd, I get something similar:

```
2020-12-04T20:24:35.852594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
2020-12-04T20:24:35.852826+00:00 app[web.1]: from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, Updater
2020-12-04T20:24:35.852831+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
2020-12-04T20:24:35.853028+00:00 app[web.1]: from .basepersistence import BasePersistence
2020-12-04T20:24:35.853033+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/basepersistence.py", line 25, in <module>
2020-12-04T20:24:35.853242+00:00 app[web.1]: from telegram import Bot
2020-12-04T20:24:35.853243+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot'
```

These are my imports:

```
import os
import telebot
import xlrd
from flask import Flask, request
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, Updater
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason - wrong library

`pip install telegram-bot`

#### Telebot

You can wanna use Telebot, you should install `pyTelegramBotAPI` instead.

#### aiogram

Also I recommend to try modern and popular framework: `aiogram`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay. Installing pyTelegramBotAPI didn't solve my problem. I'm using Heroku and it automatically imports telegram bot, I don't know why. I tried everything but nothing works. Do you suggest me to rewrite my code and try your framework? I'm stuck.

Comment: Not famillar with Heroku, but I think it's just install libs from your requirements.txt file. I also recommend to migrate to aiogram, it's not a rocket science :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install python-telegram-bot`